# How do I make best use of survivors with the 'Counseling' personal skill?

Tags: state-of-decay

> Counseling — Can come from the traits People Person, Funeral Director, Stylist, or other jobs and hobbies. This skill has no impact on combat or exploration abilities, but provides a chance to prevent community conflicts and to raise the spirits of frightened or depressed community members.

<sup>Source: [State of Decay wiki, "**Counseling**" article](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Counseling)</sup>
[image]

How do I make best use of survivors with the 'Counseling' personal skill?

- How do I quickly level up the 'Counseling' skill, if it's possible to level it up?
- What kinds of missions or activity should I have them undertake?
- Will it better improve a low morale (angry, sad, depressed, etc.) survivor's mood or attitude if I play as a survivor with the 'Counselling' skill on 'Take (survivor) out to walk' missions?
- Or should these survivors stay at home to improve community morale? (Will their 'Counseling' skill still increase?)

Answer (score 4):

According to the State of Decay Wikia, the only level-able skills are those you use while exploring/combating.

- Cardio (Improve by sprinting)
- Wits (Improve by searching, completing certain missions)
- Fighting (Improve by killing zombies in melee)
- Shooting (Improve by killing zombies with guns)
- Leadership (Improve by fighting, completing certain missions)
- Powerhouse (Improve by fighting)
- Reflexes (Improve by fighting)

All other skills cannot be improved and only affect homebase. People with Counseling skills reduce the frequency of morale-related problems at home (angry/sad/etc).

Also, according to the [Wikia](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Counseling), Counseling has no effect on the outcome of the Fear/Anger Management missions, but Leadership does.

Comment: Will it better improve a low morale (angry, sad, depressed, etc.) survivor's  mood or attitude if I play as a survivor with the 'Counselling' skill on 'take (survivor) out to walk' missions?

Comment: If what the wiki says is true then the answer's no. Leadership seems to have that role.